# Can a subordinate clause split subject and verb in the main clause?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, subjects, clauses, dependent-clause

E.g. are these correct?

> - Following the rules, **even if** it's difficult, is essential.
> - Following the rules, **although** it's difficult, is essential.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's nothing wrong with either sentence. They're both grammatical and idiomatic. The subordinate clauses you inserted in both sentences can come at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end of each sentence.

Comment: Something in me wants to get rid of the *it's* when the clause is inserted in the middle.

Comment: @R: It's optional. You don't like verbosity. Omitting the _it's_ seems a perfectly perfectly reasonable style choice to me. :-)